# containsAll comparing fails for static and instance objects

Tags: java, collections

There is need to compare two objects: one static, other is instance of a class. Two elements seems to be equal but method [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) from `java.util.collection` returns false. I need to be sure that each `TeamMember` has exactly the same set of `Teams` (the order is not important). How to check for that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static object".

Answer (score 3):

To `Collection` be able to find your own object in itself, your class `Team` must override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. So you should override those methods and then you will be able to find them in your `Collection`

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: why do i need hashCode()? isn't equals() enough?

Comment: when you override `equals()` method you should almost always override `hashCode()` method. Example is simple: when you use `Set<Team> teams = HashSet<Team>();` and when you call `teams.contains(new Team());` first of all Java computes `hashCode()` of your `new Team()` and then look into `HashSet<Team>` if under this hashCode "bucket" is something stored. If yes, Java will do linear search of that bucket calling `equals()` method on every element in that "bucket" until it finds match.